# Zoom in/out in gmail app on android when for email that only has png attachment without anything else in the body

Tags: android, html, email, gmail, html-email

I'm sending an email that its body has only img attachment.
In gmail app in android the zoom doesn't work.
Whenever I add any text to the message the zoom works.
Is there a way to make the email empty from text but still enable to zoom on image?

Comment: You mean the text shows bigger? I would say it's not the zoom. The images are resized while the text size remains the same.

Comment: @Syfer I don't mean the text shows bigger. The text shows the same. The images is resized and that's the expected behaviour. It's just doesn't happen when I don't put any text. My question is how to do it without adding unnecessary text.

Answer (score 0):

On your images use

```
width:100%;max-width:[image width];height:auto;
```

that should resize your image according to the screensizes. These will go in the style tag.  Be sure to remove the width and height attributes from the IMG tag.

Let me know if it worked